# What is the best apache/linux config for this server?

Tags: apache-2.2

2 x Intel Xeon-Woodcrest 5130-DualCore
2GB RAM
Ubuntu 10.04.0-64

In the worst case this box will be serving ~300 people requesting ~700 images at the same time. The images are around 5K each.

I can upgrade or change the machine if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only serving static content installing a reverse proxy like varnish will also greatly improve performance, although I would recommend adding a little more ram (another 2 or 4 GB) to the box.

Also don't forget to make your webserver (for static content, nginx or lighttpd are good) add expire headers to the http responses, or the reverse proxy will not perform optimal.

Answer (score 0):

So its completely static content, it only serves up images? Maybe go with nginx or lighttpd rather than apache. You could probably throw some more ram in there, 2GB isn't heaps and ram is cheap. Serving static files will be limited by I/O more than anything tho, what kind of hard drives have you got in there?
Also can you expand on what you mean by "300 people requesting 700 images at the same time"?

In fact, if all you are doing is serving images, do you even need a dedicated server or could you run in on a CDN like S3? Is this an internal or external server?